# How to pass PHP variable to JavaScript function from Blade format HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel Blade format for my HTML and I am passing multiple PHP variables to JavaScript functions.
The issue is that the variables being passed to JavaScript function could have special characters.

I want the JavaScript function to be as follows:

```
jsFunction("argument1","argument2","argument3")
```

What I get:

```
jsFunction('argument1','argument2','argument3')
```

My Blade format code is:

```
<a href="#" onclick="displayBannerInvoice('{{$bannerProperty->property_id}}','{{ $bannerProperty->id }}','{{$bannerProperty->end_date}}','{{$bannerProperty->no_of_days}}','{{$bannerProperty->total}}','{{$bannerProperty->vat_percentage}}')"></a>
```

Comment: Instead of using `onclick` and string concatenation which is very fragile and error-prone in this case, consider `json_encode` ing the data and storing the result in JavaScript variables. Then your `click` event handler set by `addEventListenter` or ... can easily read the data.

Comment: @Vohuman can you kindly give an example?

Comment: Please refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript).

Comment: change your onclick to: onlick='' instead of onclick="" so it will then be onclick='function("{{$variable}}", "{{$variable}}")'

Answer (score 6):

The best shot is to not reinvent the wheel and try searching :)

There is a package already on github https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer

It does exactly what you want. Its for Laravel 5 as well as Laravel 4.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following syntax to display a php variable in laravel blade:

```js
{!! $someVar !!}
```

example:

```js
console.log( {!! $someVar !!} );
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how I am doing it. I have a form with an update button which calls a JavaScript function.

```
{!! Form::button('Update', array('class' => 'btn btn-success', 'onClick' => 'updateTeamName(' . $team_id . ')')) !!}
```

I am passing the $team_id variable (passed to the view by the controller method) to the JavaScript function.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried many syntax and finally this solved the problem.
This is your answer:

```js
jsFunction({{"$var1"}}{{","}}{{"$var2"}})
```